# ¿Cómo mantener un kernel de Jupyter Notebook iniciado?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter

Quiero saber si **¿Hay alguna forma de mantener iniciado el kernel de una celda?**

Por ejemplo, si utilizo variables de dicha celda en otra celda, no tenga que ejecutar de nuevo el kernel y todas las celdas cada vez que inicie el notebook.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que puedes hacer es mantener Jupyter Notebook iniciado en segundo plano añadiendo `&` al final. Para ello abres una terminal y ejecutas:

`jupyter notebook &`

**Aunque cierres la terminal, Jupyter seguirá ejecutandose en segundo plano tal y como lo dejaste.**

Cuando quieras terminar el proceso, puedes buscarlo y usar `kill` para cerrarlo:

1. Lo buscamos con `ps aux | grep jupyter-notebook`. Este comando primero devuelve los procesos que se están ejecutando con `ps aux` y luego se los pasamos mediante `|` para que busque el que se llame *jupyter-notebook* con `grep`, **y nos fijamos en el número de ID que tiene.**
2. Por último acabamos el proceso con el número de ID que hemos visto: `kill 12345`